# Chartboost and InApp not working in same unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using InAppPurchase plugin in my game and now when I add chartBoost then my InApp stoped working.. I think its because of chartboost and inApp plugin have their own different activity so they have their different AndroidManifest.xml .

I tried to merger both AndroidManifest.xml into single mainfest file.but then when the chartboost called my game stop working.

does anyone face the same problem and got any solution then plz help...

Comment: sounds like very specific problem. Did you try to contact plugin developers?

Comment: hmm for that i think u need to contact or mail plugin developer..

Answer (score 0):

Zanky's right!

I'm not sure if you'll find an answer for something this specific on our help site (https://help.chartboost.com/) but please feel welcome to give it a look and then contact us (support@chartboost.com) and we can lend a hand!